# check property existence

Tags: umbraco

In umbraco, is it possible to check if certain property exist for particular node? 
For example, I am having 5 nodes and I am having media picker property for first node alone. I need to check all the nodes whether media picker property is available for nodes or not?

Comment: Are you doing this in an xslt file or in a user control?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can just check property existence by comparing to null:

```
Node somenode = new Node(myNodeID);
if (somenode.GetProperty("myProperty") != null)
{
   string myProperty = somenode.GetProperty("myProperty").Value.ToString();
   //Do something with myProperty
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Razor you can do it like this:

```
Model.HasProperty("MyPropertyAlias")
```

And you can check if the property contains a value as follows:

```
Model.HasValue("MyPropertyAlias")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
 if (Model.Content.HasValue("alias"))
 {
//placeyour code here
 }
```

Comment: You should first check that the property exists before checking for a value or I think you will get a null reference exception if for some reason it doesn't exist.